# Mongo DB query: project array element to property

Tags: mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Having following data

```
{
   "_id": "...",
   "name": "John",
   "purchases": [
       {
            "date": {
                "$date": "2016-12-20T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "amount": 1000
       },
       {
            "date": {
                "$date": "2016-12-23T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "amount": 100
       }    

   ]
}
```

How to get latest purchase amount as result field with different name?

To get next result:

```
{
    "_id": "...",
    "name": "John",
    "purchases": [
           {
                "date": {
                    "$date": "2016-12-20T00:00:00.000Z"
                },
                "amount": 1000
           },
           {
                "date": {
                    "$date": "2016-12-23T00:00:00.000Z"
                },
                "amount": 100
           }    

       ]
    },
    "latestPurchaseAmount": 100
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `$rename` take a look at this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/)

And for your last item you should look at this it will helps you [Link](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/last/)

Comment: `$rename` seems to be an update operator.
But I need to rename field due projection.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. This below query will unwind all the purchases in the collection and, sort the purchases by date descending and, limit the result to one and project the corresponding amount.

```
db.purchases.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$purchases"
}, {
    $sort: {
        "purchases.date": -1
    }
}, {
    $limit: 1
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        latestPurchaseAmount: "$purchases.amount"
    }
}]);
```

Output

```
{ "latestPurchaseAmount" : 100 }
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I need. 
What about persons without purchases, will it be output? 
Is there a way to filter out amount without miss person?

Comment: The persons without purchases will not be considered as $unwind won't return anything if the purchases array is empty or doesnt exist.